# SQL Server Management Studio 18 won't open (only splash screen pops up)

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I just installed SSMS 18 GA on a computer with only VS2019 installed, and when I try to open SSMS the splash screen will come up, but then the process exits.

Running ssms with the `-log` parameter reveals an error message:

> CreateInstance failed for package [Task Scheduler Package]Source:
>   'mscorlib' Description: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0, Version=15.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0, Version=15.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0,
>   Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>   ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0, Version=8.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0, Version=8.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly
>   assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase,
>   ObjectHandleOnStack type)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)    at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String
>   typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder,
>   Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes,
>   Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName) 
>   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String
>   typeName)
>
> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0, Version=8.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0, Version=8.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

I tried running "Repair" on SSMS, and tried a repair of `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{AAA9F15B-AF45-4562-9991-93A848D3A902}v15.0.28307.421\redist\vs2017_isoshell_for_ssms.msi`, but the problem persists.

Comment: The log file is generated by adding the `-log` parameter.  E.g.: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe" -log C:\drop\log.txt`

Comment: You can get the log as well from C:\Users\(user)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AppEnv\15.0\ActivityLog.xml without using the -log switch

Answer (score 131):

I just overlaid the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0.dll in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies` with the copy from `..\PrivateAssemblies\Interop` and the IDE opens. (Thanks to Mitch for discovering the offending DLL name.)

This looks like a popular Q & A today, so I'm glad to know this wasn't just me.

Comment: For me there was an additional `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0` folder to copy into.

Comment: Worked like a charm and a life-saver. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me. Copy *from* \PrivateAssemblies into \PublicAssemblies.

Comment: Lovely!! Thank you.

Comment: +1 Got same error after upgrading to Visual Studio 2022 and this worked for me (initial start took a few seconds and the splash screen just stays on screen as if the application has hanged, but wait for it, it eventually opens).

Answer (score 68):

As [Ronan Ariely reccomends](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/239165/16496), [an official solution has been published](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/37502512-ssms2018-installed-but-will-not-run) which recommends removing a line from `ssms.exe.config`.

In `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe.config`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <!-- ...snip... -->
    <runtime>
        <!-- ...snip... -->
        <!-- Remove this line (~line 38) -->
        <NgenBind_OptimizeNonGac enabled="1" />
        <!-- ...snip... -->
    </runtime>
    <!-- ...snip... -->
</configuration>
```

If you ran my [previous solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/revisions/237087/1) of adding the assembly to the GAC, you should probably uninstall it by running:

```
gacutil /u Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0,Version=15.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

Comment: Any version of `gacutil` should be fine.  Or [you can use `powershell`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43234102/138200) if you don't have a version of the SDK installed.

Comment: Love StackExchange for this. Totally worked for me.

Comment: Nice.. this work for me

Comment: How did you know it, man???? Thank you!

Answer (score 35):

This is known issue and there is new official workaround which published by the SSMS developers team.

You can view the open ticket at Microsoft feedback system in the following link:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/37502512-ssms2018-installed-but-will-not-run

### Short history:

**The first workaround** which was presented was to copy the file: `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0.dll`

from the directory: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Interop`

into the directory: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies`

**Later, a more focused solution was published** (which is what I used): Simply remove the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Platform\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Interop.pkgdef`

Anyhow, several days ago the team publish an update as you can see in the link above. This is a quote from the official updated response:

> The recommended workaround, in the interim, is:
>
> 1) Close all instances of SSMS
>
> 2) Edit ssms.exe.config
>
> 3) Remove the line that has the following text (should be line 38):
>   NgenBind_OptimizeNonGac enabled=“1”
>
> That’s the same change that will be in the next release of SSMS 18.x

**Note!** the location of ssms.exe.config file is in the folder: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE`

Comment: This should be the approved workaround.

Comment: Yous it should @Omzig , but for some reason it did not even got the max number of voting

Comment: Proper workaround ..!! Thans mate, this fixed the issue.

Comment: You are most welcome @MohamedAyas 

Comment: I have SQL Management Studio 2014 but I don't have such a folder. ssms.exe.config is at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio... and content has nothing to do with the mentioned here. Any help, please?

Comment: @jstuardo , This thread is about **SQL Server Management Studio 18** and **NOT** version 2014. Why do you expect to have the same folder or files or anything else which is the same, if you use different application?!? Your comment is totally **not relevant** to the thread! Best help I can give you is advise to read well explanations which you find online, check that you are actually looking at the same product and the same version of the product, and if you do not find a solution then you can use one of the online forums to start a new thread, describe your scenario fully and ask the question

Answer (score 1):

I have just crossed the same issue on a freshly built Server 2016 with SQL Server 2017 & SSMS 18.0, however it went away after 2 reboots during which the server was fully patched with March 2019 O/S patches. I'll try to do some more testing to figure out if it was really the O/S patches helping this, but I am unaware of anything else installing in the meantime on that server.

It seems more random after reboots, but what I have noticed now is that SSMS works right after installing, but then SCCM in my org starts installing various things and SSMS stops working. Now the suspect is ".NET Framework 3.5 Server Feature 2016"

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and after searching for a while for this issue, i found the following step-by-step article tackling this issue:

- [SSMS : How To Fix SQL Server Management Studio Not Opening Problem](https://www.howtosolutions.net/2019/05/fixing-microsoft-sql-server-management-studio-ssms-not-loading-problem/)

The solution provided is:

> Copy the PrivateAssemblies\Interop\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0.dll file (the one with assembly version 15.0.0.0) into the PublicAssemblies folder.

The steps were the following:

- First, as a precaution, the author renamed the existing `PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0.dll` to something else, just in case I would need that file later.
- Then he copied the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0.dll` file from `PrivateAssemblies\Interop` into the `PublicAssemblies` folder.

After this change, the SSMS loaded without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution to this problem. On the Azure Feedback item [SQL Server Management Studio 18 GA (15.0.18118.0) not compatible with .NET Framework 4.8](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/37494769-sql-server-management-studio-18-ga-15-0-18118-0#) Erich Signer suggests:

> Step 1:
>
> `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Platform\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Interop.pkgdef`
>
> Rename and make sure this file does not have the `.pkgdef` extension anymore. Or remove the file.
>
> Step 2:
>
> Remove the following Registry Key (which is created at SSMS 18 Startup using the ".pkgdef" file mentioned above):
>
> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\18.0_IsoShell_Config\RuntimeConfiguration\dependentAssembly\bindingRedirection\{8BC7AF31-B6DA-4B97-8B36-F0500DECB147}`

*<sub>Based on a comment originally left by [omzig](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/181388/omzig)</sub>*