# Microsoft SSMS 2018 cannot open (only the splash screen)

Tags: sql-server-2017, sql-server-2019

yes, i've read this [SQL Server Management Studio 18 won't open (only splash screen pops up)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/237086/sql-server-management-studio-18-wont-open-only-splash-screen-pops-up) , it work the first time. after i restart my computer, and try to open smss again, the problem happen again and i try to fix it like before, but now, it doesnt work.

this is my error log:

> 34
>       2019/05/19 23:14:19.298
>       Error
>       VisualStudio
>       CreateInstance failed for package [Async Query Service Package]Source: 'mscorlib' Description: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
> File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>    at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
>    at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
>    at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>    at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
>    at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
> 
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
> To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
> Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
> To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
>       {DD7B74B5-C1F9-411A-B22E-5E711592BC6B}
>
> ---
>
> 80004005 - E_FAIL

what i get from there is saying that the program failed to find the dll, but, the dll exist.

Comment: I'm getting the same now, where do you find the error log?

Comment: You need to make your own log via CMD.

"C:\Path\To\Your\Excutable\nameofexecutable.exe" -log C:\path\of\the\log\you\want\nameoflog.txt"

Run in cmd

Comment: By The Way, i've solved this problem by copying my friend's Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0

Comment: Microsoft gave me this answer: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035/suggestions/37502512
Seems like there is an line that should be removed from configfile.  But I copied the interop file from another place, seems to work.